# How to scope user selection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently developing a Web Application that consists of different panels and areas.
One panel contains a huge table, another panel contains a description box, etc.

Usually, users can drag their mouse and select any range of text inside an html page.
I want the user to only be able to select text inside of one panel or up to a barrier.

**For example, when the table is in focus, selecting text by mouse or hitting Ctrl-A should only select text inside of it. Not every selectable text on the page.**

```
<div id="application">
   <p>Not this text</p>
   <div id="another-panel">Nor that</div>
   <div id="special-panel-including-big-table">
       Hitting Ctrl-A here should only select THIS text
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to somehow define a barrier on a parent element (like the table panel) that prevents expanding the selection further up the DOM tree.

---

I consulted https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection and
https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/

I tried to use `stopPropagation()` on dragstart-events, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the default selection with `e.preventDefault()` and create your own selection instead.

If your table contains input elements that can get the focus you can build in an extra check for that. That is not included in my example.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'a') {
    //Prevent the default select all
    e.preventDefault();

    //Select only the contents of div#special-panel-including-big-table
    var targetEl = document.getElementById('special-panel-including-big-table');
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(targetEl);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } 
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="application">
   <p>Not this text</p>
   <div id="another-panel">Nor that</div>
   <div id="special-panel-including-big-table">
       Hitting Ctrl-A here should only select THIS text
   </div>
</div>
```